# XML Parsing with PHP using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, amazon-mws

I m working with Amazon Marketplace Web Service (Amazon MWS) to fetch products.

I need to get the title of the first product :

For the ASIN, I can get it using :

```
$xml->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product[0]->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN
```

but for the title, I dont konw how because of the "ns2".

here is the XML data :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListMatchingProductsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <ListMatchingProductsResult>
    <Products>
      <Product>
        <Identifiers>
          <MarketplaceASIN>
            <MarketplaceId>A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2</MarketplaceId>
            <ASIN>B01MYV7W6A</ASIN>
          </MarketplaceASIN>
        </Identifiers>
        <AttributeSets>
          <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-CA">
            <ns2:Binding>Automotive</ns2:Binding>
            <ns2:Brand>Multiple Manufacturers</ns2:Brand>
            <ns2:ItemDimensions>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">12</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:ItemDimensions>
            <ns2:Label>Multiple Manufacturers</ns2:Label>
            <ns2:Manufacturer>Multiple Manufacturers</ns2:Manufacturer>
            <ns2:Model>AC1000149R</ns2:Model>
            <ns2:PackageDimensions>
              <ns2:Height Units="inches">18</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Length Units="inches">78</ns2:Length>
              <ns2:Width Units="inches">38</ns2:Width>
              <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">12</ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:PackageDimensions>
            <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
            <ns2:PartNumber>AC1000149R</ns2:PartNumber>
            <ns2:ProductGroup>Automotive Parts and Accessories</ns2:ProductGroup>
            <ns2:ProductTypeName>AUTO_ACCESSORY</ns2:ProductTypeName>
            <ns2:Publisher>Multiple Manufacturers</ns2:Publisher>
            <ns2:SmallImage>
              <ns2:URL>https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31gfzCbfPRL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
              <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
              <ns2:Width Units="pixels">75</ns2:Width>
            </ns2:SmallImage>
            <ns2:Studio>Multiple Manufacturers</ns2:Studio>
            <ns2:Title>OE Replacement 2004-2006 Acura TL Bumper Cover (Partslink Number AC1000149)</ns2:Title>
          </ns2:ItemAttributes>
        </AttributeSets>
        <Relationships/>
        <SalesRankings/>
      </Product>
    </Products>
  </ListMatchingProductsResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>83360543-e16c-4c0f-a4b5-5dcca89a3075</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ListMatchingProductsResponse>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found :

```
$ItemAttributes = $xml->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product[$i]->AttributeSets->ItemAttributes;
$ItemAttributes->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd');
$titles = $ItemAttributes->xpath("//ns2:Title");  // <= this is array
```